# Can we use asteroseismology to study neutron stars?

Tags: observational-astronomy, neutron-star, asteroseismology

Asteroseismology study the propagation of sound waves inside a star to probe its internal structure. Could something similar be used to study the structure of neutron stars and put constraints on the equation of state of neutron matter?

In case this is not yet possible, is it due to a lack of a theoretical model, or to the difficulty to observe vibrations on neutron stars?

Comment: Cool question! There is indirect evidence of "star quakes" from very small but abrupt changes in the periods of pulsars, but that's probably not considered a direct asteroseismological measurement.

Comment: I wonder what physical mechanism could/would reveal the various modes on the surface since it's supported by electronic degeneracy pressure.